# How to not let the user use 0 when using the program?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have to create a program that calculates the hypotenuse of a triangle. It can only use numbers, and if the given input is not a number, then it should throw an exception. I was able to do that, however I would like the user to not be able to input 0, as a side of a triangle with 0 is no triangle at all. I tried if statements but I don't think I'm using them correctly. Please help!

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class handleexceptions1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean repeat = true;
        double _sideA = 0;
        while (repeat) {
            try {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter side A: ");
                _sideA = input.nextDouble();

                repeat = false;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Error! Please enter a valid number!");
            }
        }
        boolean repeat2= true;
        double _sideB = 0;
        while (repeat2){
            try {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter side B: ");
                _sideB = input.nextDouble();
                repeat2= false;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Error! Please enter a valid number!");
            }
        }
        double hyptonuse = Math.sqrt((_sideA*_sideA) + (_sideB*_sideB));
        System.out.println("Side C(the hyptonuse) is: "+ hyptonuse);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see an `if` statement in your code.

Comment: You could check if your variable is greater than 0 in your try/catch and then throw a new exception if it is 0.  Then you can add a new catch to handle the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your try {} scope check if your number is greater than 0. If so, repeat = false:

```
try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter side A: ");
    _sideA = input.nextDouble();
    if (_sideA > 0){
       repeat = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this instead of the line 'repeat = false' :

```
if(_sideA == 0){
repeat = true;
} else {
repeat = false;
}
```

Do that for each while loop.

Comment: Or `repeat = (_sideA == 0);`. Or `while (_sideA == 0) {`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest replacing the

```
_sideA = input.nextDouble();
```

with

```
_sideA = parseValue();
```

and moving

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

inside a new helper function, parseValue() like so:

```
private double parseValue() throws InputMismatchException
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double retVal = input.nextDouble();
    if (retVal <= 0)
    {
        throw InputMismatchException;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

You may want to use some other Exception type, in which case you would need to make sure to catch that type as well. Similarly make sure to update sideB to use new function.